# Using WatchKit, is there a method to keep the screen on?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

My app displays various countdown timers that the user will view to see when to do various tasks.  I'd like this screen to stay on display on the watch while the app is in the foreground.  Currently, the screen will auto-turn off and if I stay away from flicking my wrist, the app will even become suspended.

Is this just something I'm going to have to design around, or is there a method I can't find to change this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no method in WatchKit to programmatically keep an app alive/awake. As you've suggested, you'll have to design around this limitation.

Comment: That was my assumption - just wanted confirmation

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to have a countdown timer on the watch is to add it to the complication.

It supports a timer automatically when you provide a future date

```
CLKRelativeDateTextProvider(date: wakeupDate, style: .timer, units: .second)
```